# Electronjs ipcMain como mostrar variable en el render input tipo buscador?

Tags: javascript, mysql, html5, bootstrap, electron

no e podido como mostrar en el render de login mostrar la información que consulto con el evento `onkeydown` al `input id="username"`

que debo hacer y como debo mostrar los datos en el `<datalist id="datalistUsername">`

en el html esta lo siguiente:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline';" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- CSS only -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BmbxuPwQa2lc/FVzBcNJ7UAyJxM6wuqIj61tLrc4wSX0szH/Ev+nYRRuWlolflfl" crossorigin="anonymous">
        
    </head>
    <body class="body">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 p-4 my-auto">
                <form>
    
    
                    <div class="mb-3">
    
                        <label for="username" class="form-label">Nombre de Usuario</label>
                        <input class="form-control" list="datalistUsername" id="username" placeholder="Type to search...">
                        <datalist id="datalistUsername">
                            <option value="San Francisco">
                            <option value="New York">
                            <option value="Seattle">
                            <option value="Los Angeles">
                            <option value="Chicago">
                        </datalist>
                    <div id="userName" class="form-text">We'll never share your email with anyone else.</div>
    
                    </div>
                    <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="userpassword" class="form-label">Contraseña de Usuario</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="userpassword">
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" id="login" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Iniciar</button>
                </form>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

en el proceso principal uso lo siguiente:

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain, Notification } = require('electron')
const path = require('path'); 
let winlogin;
//ventana de login
function loginWindow () {
  winlogin = new BrowserWindow({
   width: 500,
   height: 600,
   webPreferences: {
    // nodeIntegration: true,
    // contextIsolation:true,
    preload:path.join(app.getAppPath(), './src/js/login.js')
     
   }
 })

 winlogin.loadFile('./src/ui/pages/login.html')

 // Open the DevTools
 //win.webContents.openDevTools()
}



app.whenReady().then(loginWindow)

app.on('window-all-closed', () => {
  if (process.platform !== 'darwin') {
    app.quit()
  }
})

app.on('activate', () => {
  if (BrowserWindow.getAllWindows().length === 0) {
    createWindow()
  }
})

ipcMain.handle('loginame', (event, obj) => {
  showloginname(obj)
});
function showloginname(obj){
  const porcentaje = "%"
  const {username} = obj
  const sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC"
  let consulta = db.query(sql,[porcentaje+username+porcentaje], (error, results, fields) =>{
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }

  })
}
```

y en el render:

```
const  {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
let DatalistUsername;
let btnlogin;
let name;
let password;

window.onload = function(){
    name = document.getElementById("username")
    password = document.getElementById("userpassword")
    btnlogin = document.getElementById("login")
    DatalistUsername = document.getElementById("datalistUsername")

    btnlogin.onclick = function(){
        const obj = {
            username: name.value,
            userpassword: password.value
        }

        ipcRenderer.invoke("login", obj)
    }

    name.onkeydown = function(){
        const obj = {
            username: name.value
        }

        ipcRenderer.invoke("loginame", obj)
    }

}
```

no e podido mostrar la información alguien me puede orientar por favor

Answer (score 0):

codigo HTML:

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label class="form-label">Usuario</label>
    <input class="form-control form-control-lg" list="datalistUsername" type="text" id="username" placeholder="Ingrese Nombre de Usuario" autofocus />
    <datalist id="datalistUsername">
    </datalist>
<div id="userName" class="form-text">Se mostrara una Lista de los usuarios registrados Seleccione su Usuario del Sistema.</div>
</div>
```

Primero llamamos al `ipcMain` en el proceso principal

```
const { app, BrowserWindow, ipcMain } = require('electron')
```

Luego Agregamos: `ipcMain.handle`

como continuación:

```
    ipcMain.handle('nameejemplo', (event, obj) => {
       namefunction(obj)
    });
```

Luego llamamos a la función:`namefunction`

como A continuación:

```
function namefunction(obj){
  const caracterbusc = "%"
  const {username} = obj
  const sql = "SELECT username FROM user WHERE username LIKE ? ORDER BY id DESC"
  let consulta = db.query(sql,[caracterbusc+username+caracterbusc], (error, results, fields) =>{
    if(error){
      console.log(error);
    }

    if(results.length > 0){
      winlogin.webContents.send('nameuser', results)
    }
    
  })

}
```

Hora en el render para ejecutar lo de la siguiente forma:

```
const  {ipcRenderer} = require('electron')
let name;
let listadeusuario;

window.onload = function(){
name = document.getElementById("username")
listadeusuario = document.getElementById("datalistUsername")

name.onkeydown = function(){
        const obj = {
            username: name.value
        }
        ipcRenderer.invoke("nameejemplo", obj)
    }
}
ipcRenderer.on('nameuser', (event, result) => {
  
   
    let template = ""
    const list = result
    list.forEach(element => {
       template+=`
                <option value="${element.username}">                
                ` 
    });
      
    listadeusuario.innerHTML = template 
 
 });
```

Gracias a todos pero así solucione.